# Regex: Difference betwen negative lookbehind and negation

Tags: regex, lookbehind, negative-lookbehind

From [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

> `\b\w+(?<!s)\b`. This is definitely not the same as `\b\w+[^s]\b`. When applied to `Jon's`, the former will match `Jon` and the latter `Jon'` (including the apostrophe). I will leave it up to you to figure out why. (Hint: \b matches between the apostrophe and the s). The latter will also not match single-letter words like "a" or "I".

Can you explain why ?

Also, can you make clear what exacly `\b` does, and why it matches between the apostrophe and the `s` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\b` is a zero-width assertion that means [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html). These character positions (taken from that link) are considered word boundaries:

> - Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a word character.
> - After the last character in the string, if the last character is a word character.
> - Between two characters in the string, where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.

Word characters are of course any `\w`. `s` is a word character, but `'` is not. In the above example, the area between the `'` and the `s` is a word boundary.

The string `"Jon's"` looks like this if I highlight the anchors and boundaries (the first and last `\b`s occur in the same positions as `^` and `$`): `^Jon\b'\bs$`

The negative lookbehind assertion `(?<!s)\b` means it will only match *a word boundary if it's not preceded by the letter `s`* (i.e. the last word character is not an `s`). So it looks for a word boundary under a certain condition.

Therefore the first regex works like this:

1. `\b\w+` matches the first three letters `J` `o` `n`.
2. There's actually another word boundary between `n` and `'` as shown above, so `(?<!s)\b` matches *this word boundary* because it's preceded by an `n`, not an `s`.
3. Since the end of the pattern has been reached, the resultant match is `Jon`.

The complementary character class `[^s]\b` means it will match *any character that is not the letter `s`*, followed by a word boundary. Unlike the above, this looks for one character followed by a word boundary.

Therefore the second regex works like this:

1. `\b\w+` matches the first three letters `J` `o` `n`.
2. Since the `'` is not the letter `s` (it fulfills the character class `[^s]`), and it's followed by a word boundary (between `'` and `s`), it's matched.
3. Since the end of the pattern has been reached, the resultant match is `Jon'`. The letter `s` is *not* matched because the word boundary before it has already been matched.

Comment: +1, but one quibble: "`^` and `$` are special kinds of `\b`" is incorrect.  `\b` just happens to match the same positions the anchors do in this case.  If you want to indicate the spots where `\b` *can* match, I think this works better: `\bJon\b'\bs\b`.

Comment: Oops back: I edited my comment to remove the the anchors entirely (but I don't insist on that one ☺).

Comment: @Alan Moore, `^`, `$` and `\b` are considered anchors. `$` can also match in multiple spots in most strings (before and after a trailing newline), even without /m. Under /m, Both `^` and `$` can match in multiple places. I find grouping `\b` with `^` and `$`  matches people's mental model and not wholly inaccurate.

Comment: @ikegami: Strictly speaking, *anchor* is a synonym for *zero-width assertion*, but it's commonly used to refer the subset of ZWA's associated with line boundaries (`^`, `$`, `\A`, `\Z`, `\z`), and that's how I was using it.  I have no objection to calling `\b` an anchor too, but BC seemed to be implying a relationship that doesn't exist (`^` and `$` as special-case word boundaries), and I wanted to clear that up.

Answer (score 1):

The example is trying to demonstrate that lookaheads and lookbehinds can be used to create "and" conditions.

---

```
\b\w+(?<!s)\b
```

could also be written as

```
\b\w*\w(?<!s)\b
```

That gives us

```
\b\w*[^s]\b    vs    \b\w*\w(?<!s)\b
```

I did that so we can ignore the irrelevant. (The `\b` are simply distractions in this example.) We have

```
[^s]    vs    \w(?<!s)
```

On the left, we can match any *character* except "s"

On the right, we can match any *word character* except "s"

By the way,

```
\w(?<!s)
```

could also be written

```
(?!s)\w      # Not followed by "s" and followed by \w
```

Comment: +1. That whole paragraph in the source article is a muddled mess, far below Jan's usual standard. This point should have been presented in a separate section (along with the discussion of `q[^u]` vs. `q(?!u)` from the Character Classes page), where it could be given a more thorough treatment with a better-chosen example.